# RSPEC is not recognizing my module or class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, module, ruby-2.0

In `lib/A/B/C.rb` of my Rails 4 program I have a class as follows:

```
module A
    module B
        class C
        end
    end
end
```

I would like to test this class and am trying to write an RSPEC test in `spec/lib/A/B/C_spec.rb`.  The file is as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe A::B::C do
end
```

However, I'm getting this error when I run the test:

```
{path}/spec/lib/A/B/C.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant A (NameError)
```

As per other posts, I tried to fix the problem by adding `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")` and similar into `config/application.rb`.  But it doesn't seem to be working.  How can I get the test to recognize the modules and class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this myself.  Here is how:

(1) In `spec/lib/A/B/C_spec.rb`, I replaced `spec_helper` with `rails_helper`.

(2) I added this line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")
```